# sort file by their last modified date with QfileSystemModel

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I want to use QtableView and QfileSystemModel to show all the files in a folder , I want the file list is sorted by their last modified date ,now I have already reimplement QsortFilterProxyModel ,
my code is here 
http://codepad.org/CE2zxrT3
but I don’t know what index should I give to setRootIndex() , can you help ?

Comment: Did you try `model.sort(3);` already?

Comment: it already in my code ,don't you notice it ?

Comment: Yes I saw it, but you sort the proxy not the QFileSystemModel itself. Just remove the proxy and try `model.sort(3);`

Comment: The base class implementation does nothing.http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qabstractitemmodel.html#sort

Comment: The method is reimplemented in the QFileSystemModel. See [qfilesystemmodel.cpp source](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/gui/dialogs/qfilesystemmodel.cpp#line1160) and [QFileSystemModel documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfilesystemmodel.html#sort).